# Validar vários formulários de uma só vez - Simulado

Tags: php, javascript, sql, html5

Estou criando um site de simulados e estou com dificuldade em corrigí-lo, pois não sei como validar inúmeros formulários de uma vez.

O que acontece:

- Tenho perguntas que são selecionadas de forma aleatória pelo banco de dados;
- Essas perguntas ficam dentro de um formulário com suas alternativas;
- Quero corrigí-las (saindo da página ou não) ao clicar em apenas um `submit` - O simulado possui 10 questões ao todo.

Obs: Tentei usar `$_SESSION[]` e funcionou, mas apenas com um exemplo.
Espero que tenha passado minha ideia, segue um trecho de código:

```
<div class="plataforma_layout_grade" data-reactid="42">
  <div class="plataforma_layout_mestre" data-reactid="58">
    <!--Criação de categoria de simulado-->
    <div class="topico-mestre" data-reactid="59">
      <h1 class="topico-titulo" data-reactid="60"><?php echo"$materia";?></h1>
    </div>
    <div>

      <?php 
        $sql="select * from questoes where id_materia=$disciplina order by rand() limit 10";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);

        while ($vetor=mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)):

          $_SESSION["id_questao"] = $vetor[0];
          $id=$vetor[0];
          $pergunta = $vetor[1];
          $imagem = $vetor[2];
          $A = $vetor[3];
          $B = $vetor[4];
          $C = $vetor[5];
          $D = $vetor[6];
          $E = $vetor[7];
          $_SESSION["resposta"] = $vetor[8];
          $resposta=$vetor[8];
      ?>

      <div style="margin-left: 20px;margin-right: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">
        <form method="POST" action="VALIDAR_SIMULADO.PHP" name="codigo"  >

            <fieldset >
              <legend value="<?php echo'$id'; ?>">Cod. <?php echo"$id"; ?></legend>
              <p style="margin-top: -2px;margin-bottom: 8px;"  value="<?php echo'$id'; ?>"> <?php echo"$pergunta"; ?> <br>
              <p><label>A) <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="A"> <?php echo"$A"; ?></label></p>
              <p><label>B) <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="B"> <?php echo"$B"; ?></label></p>
              <p><label>C) <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="C"> <?php echo"$C"; ?></label></p>
              <p><label>D) <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="D"> <?php echo"$D"; ?></label></p>
              <p style="margin-bottom:-2px;"><label>E) <input type="radio" name="alternativa" value="E"> <?php echo"$E"; ?></label></p>
            </fieldset>
      </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

      <input type="submit" name="corrigir" value="Corrigir">
      </form>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O que deveria ser este `p` com a propriedade `value` dentro do `fieldset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, você não precisa se múltiplos formulários em sua página. Apenas um dá conta do recado. A única alteração que precisa fazer para isso é diferenciar os campos entre as questões. Você pode definir os `value` dos `input` como listas, definido o índice da lista. Por exemplo:

```
<form action="validar_simulado.php" method="post">

  <?php $i = 0; ?>

  <?php while($vetor = mysqli_fetch_row($resultado)): ?>

    <?php list($id, $pergunta, $imagem, $a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $resposta) = $vetor; ?>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Questão <?= $i; ?></legend>
      <p><?= $pergunta; ?></p>
      <input type="hidden" name="id[<?= $i; ?>]" value="<?= $id; ?>">
      <input type="radio" name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="a" checked> <?= $a; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="b"> <?= $b; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="c"> <?= $c; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="d"> <?= $d; ?>
      <input type="radio" name="alternativa[<?= $i; ?>]" value="e"> <?= $e; ?>
    </fieldset>

    <?php i++; ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

  <input type="submit" name="corrigir" value="Corrigir">
</form>
```

Este código gerará um HTML semelhante à:

> Código CSS foi apenas para mão deixar o resultado tão feio e o JavaScript é para executar algo quando pressionado o botão.

```js
$(() => {

  $("input[type='submit']").on('click', () => {
    console.log("Questão 1: " + $('input[name="alternativa[0]"]:checked').val());
    console.log("Questão 2: " + $('input[name="alternativa[1]"]:checked').val());
  });

});
```

```css
fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

fieldset p {
  font-weight: bold;
}

fieldset legend {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="validar_simulado.php" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Questão 1</legend>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[0]" value="5">
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[0]" value="a" checked> A
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[0]" value="b"> B
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[0]" value="c"> C
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[0]" value="d"> D
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[0]" value="e"> E
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Questão 2</legend>
    <p>Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a?</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[1]" value="32">
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[1]" value="a" checked> A
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[1]" value="b"> B
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[1]" value="c"> C
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[1]" value="d"> D
    <input type="radio" name="alternativa[1]" value="e"> E
  </fieldset>
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="corrigir" value="Corrigir">
</form>
```

Perceba que com JavaScript já é possível recuperar todas as respostas, mas o mas fácil a se implementar é corrigí-las no PHP. Da maneira que está, o PHP receberá dois *arrays* via POST: `$_POST['id']` e `$_POST['alternativa']`. O *array* `id` armazena os `id` das questões no banco de dados e servirá para corrigir efetivamente as questões. O *array* `alternativa` armazena as respostas dadas.

***array* `id`**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 32
)
```

Os valores 5 e 32 são hipotéticos e representam os `id` das questões que foram selecionadas do banco aleatoriamente.

***array* `alternativa`**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => c
    [2] => b
    [3] => a
    [4] => a
    [5] => d
    [6] => b
    [7] => c
    [8] => e
    [9] => c
)
```

Os valores também são hipotéticos e representam as respostas dadas às perguntas.

Agora basta você selecionar do banco de dados as questões cujo `id` pertence ao vetor `id`, algo parecido com:

```
"SELECT * FROM questoes WHERE id IN {$id}"
```

E iterar sobre o resultado, verificando se a resposta presente no vetor `alternativa` é igual ao valor presente na coluna `resposta`.

Comment: onde eu boto o :
       


        $(() => {

  $("input[type='submit']").on('click', () => {
    console.log("Questão 1: " + $('input[name="alternativa[0]"]:checked').val());
    console.log("Questão 2: " + $('input[name="alternativa[1]"]:checked').val());
  });

});

Comment: Vide nota (destacada com fundo amarelo). Este código JavaScript não é necessário para a solução, apenas existe para deixar o exemplo aqui verificável.

Comment: Entendi, mas ainda não estou conseguindo corrigir...
estou usando este comando: "select * from questoes  WHERE id_questao=$id and resposta=$resposta". Porém não dá certo. Teria como me esclarecer melhor como corrigi-las?

Comment: você poderia me exemplificar como ficaria a correção delas?

Comment: Já consegui fazer conforme me explicou, muito obrigado!